# Why we need at most $2n$ examples to determine an axis aligned rectangle

Tags: machine-learning, learning-theory

In Ben-David & et al.'s *Understanding Machine Learning*, the authors wrote:

> Let $\mathcal{H}_n$ be the class of axis aligned rectangles in $\mathbb{R}^n$ , namely,
> $$
> \mathcal{H}_n = \{h(a_1,\dots,a_n, b_1,\dots, b_n) :\forall i,a_i \le b_i\}
> $$
> where
> $$
> h(a_1,\dots,a_n, b_1,\dots, b_n)(x,y)=
> \begin{cases}
> 1\text{ if } \forall i, x_i\in (a_i, b_i)\\
> 0\text{ otherwise }
> \end{cases}
> $$

In the section for *Efficiently Learnable in the Realizable Case* just below the above paragraph, they set out an implementation of ERM rule for this hypothesis class as follows:

> for each $i \in [n]$, set $a_i =\min\{x_i :(x,1)\in S\}$ and $b_i =\max\{x_i :(x,1)\in S\}$. In words,we take $a_i$ to be the minimal value of the $i$'th coordinate of a positive example in S and bi to be the maximal value of the $i$'th coordinate of a positive example in $S$

Later, in the section for *Not Efficiently Learnable in the Agnostic Case*, they wrote:

> recall the implementation of the ERM rule we presented for the realizable case, from which it follows that an axis aligned rectangle is determined by at most $2n$ examples.

I don't understand why we need up to $2n$ to determine the axis aligned rectangle. Would just one example is enough to determine a rectangle based on the learning rule specified above?

The online version of the book can be found [here](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/%7Eshais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/understanding-machine-learning-theory-algorithms.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

It's not really true the any sample of size *2n* (all with positive label) can be used to determine the rectangle. Take for example the following sample $S$:

$$
S=\{(\mathbf{x}_i, 1): \mathbf{x}_{i} = \mathbf{x}_{j}, \forall i, j\in[2n], i\ne j\}.
$$

This training set $S$ contains just one (positive) example sampled repeatedly.

Even for a sample with distinct (positive) examples, it's still not enough to construct a rectangle. Take $S$ as follows:

$$
S=\{(\mathbf{x}_i, 1): x_{i, 1} \ne x_{j, 1}\text{ and }x_{i, h} = x_{j, h}, \forall i, j\in[2n], i\ne j\text{ and }h\in\{2,...,n\}\},
$$

where $x_{i,j}$ denotes the $j$th coordinate of the $i$th example in the sample $S$.

The above training set $S$ contains examples whose coordinates are the same except the first one.